# Serve static files from another server NodeJS

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I have 2 separate server running, localhost:3000 and localhost:3002

localhost:3000 is basically a cms which handles CRUD operations for front-end.

I upload images in localhost:3000 that will be used on localhost:3002, so the directory points to localhost:3000/img/default.jpg.

The problem is, when I want to use the default.jpg, I have to use the absolute path, in order for me to display the image in localhost:3002

Example:

```
<img src="http://localhost:3000/img/default.jpg">
```

What I want to do is to just use /img/default.jpg

```
<img src="/img/default.jpg">
```

How can I achieve this? Is this even possible?

I tried using

```
app.use(express.static('localhost:3000'));
```

But as you expected, it's not working.

Comment: is this question related to your dev setup only? if you are using the webpack dev server it also is able to proxy requests, exactly suited for your usecase.

Comment: @zaphod1984 it's a problem on my production setup. I can use absolute paths, but as much as possible, I want to avoid exposing the url of my back-end

Comment: i see. the most elegant solution would be to use nginx as a reverse proxy, proxying all requests to a certain path through to the backend. https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/web-server/reverse-proxy/ In a similar setup I had a node API server and another server serving the static front end, via nginx both running under the same URL.